# Plot list of images with RGB values in numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays that are RGB values of 3 images, as below:

```
array([[ 38,  45,  48],
   [ 38,  45,  48],
   [ 38,  45,  48],
   ...,
   [134, 125, 101],
   [134, 125, 101],
   [134, 125, 101]], dtype=uint8)
```

This has been generated with the code as shown below:

```
r, c, l = img_array.shape
img_disp = np.reshape(image, (r, c, l), order="C")
arr = img_disp.astype(dtype='uint8')
img = np.asarray(Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGB'))
img_to_display = np.vstack(img)
```

I'm trying to plot these images in a jupyter notebook.

Using plt.figure() and imshow() as suggested in other posts gives the following error.

```
for ima in images:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(ima)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (3,) for image data
```

May be a small thing, but I'm not able to get this around. The shape of my list is (255440, 3).

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `for ima in images:` is just taking `[ 38,  45,  48]` . That is why it is throwing error. Instead of using `np.vstack` u can use python `list`. Otherwise you need to use proper index to get full image.

Comment: How was `images` generated?

Comment: Thank you @Epsi95. that was it!! Be blessed!